# How to log errors in VueJS project, deployed on nginx docker image?

Tags: docker, nginx, vue.js, logging, vuejs2

I'm having a `VueJS` project, which is deployed using a `nginx` docker image.

My `.Dockerfile` looks like:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i npm@latest -g && npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And my `nginx.conf` looks like:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  index index.html;

  location / {
    # Support the HTML5 History mode of the vue-router.
    # https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

Now I'm looking for a way to set up some kind of logger, so that any potential errors that may happens in the application, to be written in some `.log` file on the server. Since the application is already on the production, I would like when I will open this file (where I will be able to log the errors) to see any potential warnings / errors that are present in the application and that may harm the normal flow of the users.

Since `VueJS` is a client side `JavaScript` frame-work, I'm not sure how to put all of this together and on which side I will need to add the logger, so therefore I shared the code from the docker-sizing flow. At the moment what I'm doing is just adding the `console.log` messages, but this will not help to me when I will want to review the potential errors.

Comment: You will have to post any client errors to a backend service (web service, etc) and save the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a 3rd party logging service like Loggly to do this.  Create an account, and then you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/loggly to setup a connection:

```
  var loggly = require('loggly');

  var client = loggly.createClient({
    token: "your-really-long-input-token",
    subdomain: "your-subdomain",
    auth: {
      username: "your-username",
      password: "your-password"
    }
  });
```

And then you simply log like this:

```
  client.log('127.0.0.1 - oops i did it again');
```

You then log into their service to see the log and a bunch of tools for analysis.

There are other logging services like Logzio, etc.